# Please help to add audio noise while using "mpdecimate,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB"

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, automation, ffmpeg-filters

I have an audio, named noise.mp3. And I want `mpdecimate` to not just remove all static frames, but replace them with black screen and/or audio noise (which I can use in Adobe Premiere to edit them) and give me the original length of the video.

To be honest, I don’t really want to use exactly this way... I would like to use symbiosis of Duplicate Frame Remover plugin (or this function of mpdecimate) + Silence Remover for Adobe Premiere. But the issue is that the first option just removes them and outputs the video without pauses and the second one works only based on audio (but I have no audio in my video).

But I need the cut-out moments to be turned off, moved to another track, or to have audio noise instead of static frames. To be able to analyse and edit them further. As it works in Silence Remover or AutoCut (but they work only by analysing sound):

[Screenshot example as I want to see it (and how Silence Remover and etc works)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQ8t3.png)

I couldn't find that symbiosis, so I want to try to put audio noise instead of static frames. And then I’ll be able to use Silent Remover to auto-cut it all.

I've already spent a lot of hours trying to do this with ChatGPT, but it didn't work.
There are two ways left for me: FFmpeg can't do it /or/ the developers will help how to do it right!

Help me to figure out please!

Comment: Hello, you spent hours on trying, but you forgot to spend few minutes on showing example(s) of what you tried.